# Order number and strings putting strings last

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a SQL statement that selects and orders numbers in DESC but put all strings last

so mysql is:

```
"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY price DESC"
```

and that gives me something like

```
test
best offer
6000
100
10
```

what I want is:

```
6000
100
10
test
best offer
```

or (doesnt matter)

```
6000
100
10
best offer
test
```

Comment: Your SQL statement is returning results in *descending* order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
ORDER BY price * 1 DESC
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fe43/4)

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working, does it matter that the column is varchar

Comment: Got it! i had to change it to `SELECT * FROM posts 
ORDER BY price * 1 DESC`

Answer (score 1):

I think want you actually want is:

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY value ASC;
```

which returns:

```
10
100
6000
best offer
test
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad2fb/2)

Comment: I don't understand why you linked that. Looks like it works fine for me, all of the numbers are in *ascending* order like the question asks for.

Comment: That's not what he wants - he's asked for descending order, but with numbers preceding text.

Comment: I was going from the text in the question, which says *ASC*. So now I am unclear whether they want descending or ascending. Waiting for them to verify.

Comment: Ah yes I was going off their example - very confusing!

Comment: ah sorry the text was a typo i want what i have in my example

Answer (score 0):

If you generally do not care about performance, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
ORDER BY
  CASE CAST(price AS int) WHEN 0 THEN ' ' ELSE price END DESC,
  price ASC;
```

You might need the casts to `int` depending on your database.

You can also fiddle with the first expression to get the results you want. The point is that you have to sort first by whether it's a number or not and then the actual content.

The problem is that this you can't use any indexes this way. If you are allowed to change the database structure, it would be better to split the data into two columns. An `int` column with the price and a `varchar` column with the price description (in which case the first column is `NULL`). Then you can do faster queries.